# Is it possible to create a C# class from xml? 

Tags: c#, xml

Is it possible to create a C# class from xml?

suppose my xml is like,

```
<Person>
    <Name>aaaa</Name>
    <Email>bbb</Email>
</Person>
```

then Person would be the classname and name and email must be my properties. And how would it handle collections or potential sub objects?

```
<Person>
    <Name>aaaa</Name>
    <Email>bbb</Email>
    <PhoneNumbers>
        <Number Type="Cell">5555555</Number>
        <Number Type="Home">5555554</Number>
    </PhoneNumbers>
</Person>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your requirement?  Do you want to take some xml and create and *instance* of a class from it or do you want to actually generate a c# class file (.cs) from it?

Comment: I just got to know that i can create a class from xsd using xsd.exe, Since i am getting xml at runtime (dataset.GetXML()) shall i create xsd without using command prompt meaning in my same function only where i am getting my xml?

Let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XSD.exe to generate a class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: +1 because it's the right answer but it probably won't be marked as such.

Comment: This xml will gonna generate from dataset. So is it a good idea to go for xsd?

Answer (score 1):

The XML Schema Definition (xsd.exe) tool allows you to generate common language runtime classes from XML files. More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I love it when two people type up the same answer at the same time. +1 for you, since you were probably editing when msmucker entered their answer.

Comment: without that do i have any options?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean xml serialization, you can use this as an example.  Note the use of the Xml attributes to control the serializion/deserialization:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ThrowAwayCSConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Create an instance of the Person
            Person p = new Person { Name = "John Doe", Email = "jdoe@someisp.com" };
            p.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber { Type = "Home", Number = "999-555-1234" });
            p.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber { Type = "Work", Number = "999-555-9876" });

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

            //serialize it to xml
            using (StringWriter wrt = new StringWriter(output))
            {
                xSer.Serialize(wrt, p);
            }

            //Print the output
            Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());


            //Deserialize the xml string back to an instance of Person
            Person p2 = null;
            using (StringReader rdr = new StringReader(output.ToString()))
            {
                p2 = xSer.Deserialize(rdr) as Person;
            }

            //Use p2 instance here
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nName: {0},  Email: {1}, has {2} phone numbers:", p2.Name, p2.Email, p2.PhoneNumbers.Count);
            foreach (var number in p2.PhoneNumbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    {0}:  {1}", number.Type, number.Number);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PhoneNumber))]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [XmlArrayItem("Number")]
        public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class PhoneNumber
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output from this code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>John Doe</Name>
  <Email>jdoe@someisp.com</Email>
  <PhoneNumbers>
    <Number Type="Home">999-555-1234</Number>
    <Number Type="Work">999-555-9876</Number>
  </PhoneNumbers>
</Person>

Name: John Doe,  Email: jdoe@someisp.com, has 2 phone numbers:
    Home:  999-555-1234
    Work:  999-555-9876
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Person whetever have been taken in this example has to be created dynamically. meaning , I dont have any class i will have xml generated from dataset and want to convert to class.